# don't Return file to Editor in httpHandler on Asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, redactor.js

I use httpHander to Upload file and return it to Editor .

It's Save file but doesn't return image to editor . my code to do this is :

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files["file"];
        string path=HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")+"/Images/"+file.FileName;
        file.SaveAs(path);
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        context.Response.Write("<img src='"+path+"'/>");
    }
```

and my config of redactor is:

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $(".editor").redactor({
                            imageUpload: "Upload.ashx/ProcessRequest()",
                            fileUpload: "Upload.ashx/ProcessRequest()",
                            linkFileUpload: "Upload.ashx/ProcessRequest()"
                            ,autoformat: false
                            , convertDivs: false
                        });

                    });
</script>
```

and :

```
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtContnt" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="editor"></asp:TextBox>
```

My editor is :redactor and I use asp.net web forms .
httphandler work very well but don't return file to editor

Answer (score 0):

Your path is incorrect. `Server.MapPath` returns an absolute (file system) path, not a path that the web browser can use. Also, according to [this document](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/upload-images/), the expected response is a JSON string, not an img tag.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files["file"];
    string virtualPath = "/Images/" + file.FileName;
    string path=HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + virtualPath;
    file.SaveAs(path);
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    context.Response.Write(@"{ 'filelink': '" + virtualPath + "' }");
}
```

Comment: You need to explain better what your "editor" is. How is this HttpHandler being used? Also, it doesn't work in what way?